# What is the alternative of getMat() of Facerecognizer class in opencv3.00?

Tags: c++, opencv, face-recognition

I want to follow the tutorials of the face recognition with opencv. But in the tutorial source code example `getMat()` method is used, which shows an error :

> class cv::face::FaceRecognizer has no member "getMat".

After some searching I found out that opencv3.00 has deprecated that method. What can I use instead of `getMat()` now in opencv3.0?

This is the [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/face/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html) I am trying to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the new API [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dd7/classcv_1_1face_1_1BasicFaceRecognizer.html#gsc.tab=0).

Replace `model->getMat("eigenvalues")` with `model->getEigenValues()`, `model->getMat("mean")` with `model->getMean()`, etc...