# 'cv2.face_BasicFaceRecognizer' object has no attribute 'getParams' Python

Tags: python, opencv, parameters, face-recognition, eigenvector

I'm having some trouble creating a face recognition system with OpenCV and Python. I was trying to use the documentation given by Philipp Wagner, and I have the following code:

```
import os
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np

def normalize(X, low, high, dtype=None):
    """Normalizes a given array in X to a value between low and high."""
    X = np.asarray(X)
    minX, maxX = np.min(X), np.max(X)
    # normalize to [0...1].
    X = X - float(minX)
    X = X / float((maxX - minX))
    # scale to [low...high].
    X = X * (high-low)
    X = X + low
    if dtype is None:
        return np.asarray(X)
    return np.asarray(X, dtype=dtype)


def read_images(path, sz=None):
    """Reads the images in a given folder, resizes images on the fly if size is given.
    Args:
        path: Path to a folder with subfolders representing the subjects (persons).
        sz: A tuple with the size Resizes
    Returns:
        A list [X,y]

            X: The images, which is a Python list of numpy arrays.
            y: The corresponding labels (the unique number of the subject, person) in a Python list.
    """
    c = 0
    X,y = [], []
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for subdirname in dirnames:
            subject_path = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
            for filename in os.listdir(subject_path):
                try:
                    im = cv2.imread(os.path.join(subject_path, filename), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                # resize to given size (if given)
                    if (sz is not None):
                        im = cv2.resize(im, sz)
                    X.append(np.asarray(im, dtype=np.uint8))
                    y.append(c)
                except IOError, (errno, strerror):
                    print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
                except:
                    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
                    raise
            c = c+1
    return [X,y]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    out_dir = None

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print "USAGE: facerec_demo.py </path/to/images> [</path/to/store/images/at>]"
        sys.exit()

    [X,y] = read_images(sys.argv[1])

    y = np.asarray(y, dtype=np.int32)
    # If a out_dir is given, set it:
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        out_dir = sys.argv[2]

    model = cv2.face.createEigenFaceRecognizer()
    model.train(np.asarray(X), np.asarray(y))
    model.save('individual.xml')

    [p_label, p_confidence] = model.predict(np.asarray(X[0]))
    # Print it:
    print "Predicted label = %d (confidence=%.2f)" % (p_label, p_confidence)

    print model.getParams()
    # Now let's get some data:
    mean = model.getMat("mean")
    eigenvectors = model.getMat("eigenvectors")
    # We'll save the mean, by first normalizing it:
    mean_norm = normalize(mean, 0, 255, dtype=np.uint8)
    mean_resized = mean_norm.reshape(X[0].shape)
    if out_dir is None:
        cv2.imshow("mean", mean_resized)
    else:
        cv2.imwrite("%s/mean.png" % (out_dir), mean_resized)
    for i in xrange(min(len(X), 16)):
        eigenvector_i = eigenvectors[:,i].reshape(X[0].shape)
        eigenvector_i_norm = normalize(eigenvector_i, 0, 255, dtype=np.uint8)
        if out_dir is None:
            cv2.imshow("%s/eigenface_%d" % (out_dir,i), eigenvector_i_norm)
        else:
            cv2.imwrite("%s/eigenface_%d.png" % (out_dir,i), eigenvector_i_norm)

    if out_dir is None:
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But it keeps me getting the following error:

```
print model.getParams()
AttributeError: 'cv2.face_BasicFaceRecognizer' object has no attribute   'getParams'
```

Any idea why I can't get the any parameters? I thought that maybe it is because of the incorporation of the submodule cv2.face,and therefore it might be some alternative to model.getParams() as well as getMat() but I'm just guessing... 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33262964/5008845) answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too late but this what I did.

First, to see the list of methods that supports your cv2.face

```
model = cv2.face.createEigenFaceRecognizer ()
help (model)
```

And as you'll notice, there are some changes no longer used: `model.getMat ("mean")` now only used `mean = model.getMean()`.

I hope it helps you :)

Comment: Thank you! It's not too late cause other people are trying to use this code.